# How to make Google map draggable and keep marker in the center of the screen on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

How to configure [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) in Flutter in oder to keep the marker in the center of the map while user will drag the map and get new position with new latitude and longitude, e.g. Uber

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `GoogleMap` inside `Stack` then put your cursor widget in the `Center` on the top of your `GoogleMap` as follow:

```
  Stack(
    children: [
      GoogleMap(),
      Center(child: CursorrWidget()),
    ],
  );
```

To calculate your cursor latitude and longitude call this function when notifying `onCameraIdle`:

```
GoogleMap(
  onCameraIdle: () {
    LatLngBounds bounds = mapController.getVisibleRegion();
    final lon = (bounds.northeast.longitude + bounds.southwest.longitude) / 2;
    final lat = (bounds.northeast.latitude + bounds.southwest.latitude) / 2;
  }
)
```